# Can I edit a workbook using Excel Services?

Tags: web-part, excel, services

I created a web part putting my Excel worksheet on one of my Document Library, so I can have the live view of that worksheet without opening it again and again, my question is, can I edit that worksheet by just using that view/webpart that i created? not by opening the worksheet on a web browser/ ms office app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Excel Web Access Web Part it's not possible to edit the workbook in such a way that you save content.

> 2. Excel Web Access    is a Web Part. It can display all or part of an Excel workbook, and enables interaction with the workbook in a browser by using Dynamic Hierarchical Tag Markup Language (DHTML) and JavaScript. Because Excel Web Access is a Web Part, you can add it to a site page such as a team site, and then re-use on another page at any time with no need to download an ActiveX control to your computer. In addition, you can connect the Excel Web Access Web Part to other Web Parts, such as filters, charts, and lists.

So you need to open your workbook and, provided you have the appropriate permissions, you can edit the workbook and rendering a different content based on your latest updates.

Reference: [Getting Started with Excel Services and Excel Web Access](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/getting-started-with-excel-services)

Comment: I'm very new to Sharepoint and Thank you for this answer @benny!

BTW, I have a follow up question, the article is about sharepoint 2010, does the answer is applicable also in Sharepoint 2013?

Comment: @spideynok You're welcome! And yes, the Excel Services hasn't changed in such a way that the article is incorrect. You can still use it as guide.

Comment: Hi again @benny I'm very confused now because my boss told me that it's possible to edit the data using the Excel service on web part, but I also sent an email to Destin the author of this article http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/how-to-configure-excel-services-in-sharepoint-2013/ and he told me that you can edit it one web browser but not on the excel service.

Comment: @spideynok It's cofusing. He can edit variables in the web part, but he can't save his work from there. All changes he does, is invisible to other users. And if he reloads the page, the changes made will be gone.

Comment: Hi @benny Thank you for guiding me, I think i have an idea now that Excel Web Access Web Part is most likely a "view mode" of my workbook, am I right? Because I personally asked my colleague and he says that I still need to open the excel file to edit the data.

Comment: @spideynok That's right. You can edit **but not save** the work from the web part