# How to Edit a Excel Documents on Browser in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: excel, excel-services

I must Enable editing in browser Sharepoint 2013 Excel Document. And i Cant do it. How could I enable this to editing any Excel document in browser at Sharepoint 2013 ?

Answer (score 1):

First, Start the Excel Calculation Services service in Services on Server. Then

> ## Create an Excel Services service application
>
> 1. On the Central Administration home page, under Application Management, click Manage service applications.
> 2. On the Manage Service Applications page, click New, and then click Excel Services Application.
> 3. In the Name section, type a name for the service application in the text box.
> 4. Select the Create new application pool option and type a name for the application pool in the text box.
> 5. Select the Configurable option, and from the drop-down list, select the account that you created to run the application pool.
> 6. Click OK.

Reference: [Configure Excel Services in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219698.aspx)

Comment: But I have got Excel Services ant turned on Excel Calculation Services.

Comment: I can read. I want to edit Excel

Comment: @GrzegorzZ Did you create Excel Services service application?

Comment: If it doesn't work, you have to use Office Web Apps 2013

Comment: See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/137999/6382 for more info

Comment: If I want to open PDF & DOC in browser, then what will I need? **Excel Service** or **Office Web Apps**? @BennySkogberg. I just need this information. Please help

Comment: And How much Cost Office Web Apps ? Whot it sort of Code ?

Comment: For PDF and DOC(X) you'll need Office Web Apps https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219455.aspx